# How can i get PHP login script to log users in correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am new to PHP and I am trying to develop a simple login system where it echoes a success message and redirects to a secure page and when details are wrong, it echoes an error message and reloads the login form.

I have been trying to for a while now and cannot figure it out, even though I have some functionality in terms of it directing to the correct page.

My database on PhpMyAdmin is correctly configured. Also, any help on sessions would be greatly appreciated.

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "cornwall";

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','cornwall','ibill');
// This code creates a connection to the MySQL database in PHPMyAdmin named 'ibill':

$username =  $_POST['username'];
$password =  $_POST['password'];
//These are the different PHP variables that store my posted data.

$login="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $login);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
//This is the query that will be sent to the MySQL server.

if($count==1)
{
  header('Location: http://localhost/projects/ibill_v3/html/main.html#home');
  exit();
}
//This checks the 'user_details' database for correct user registration details and if successful, directs to home page.
else {
   header('Location: http://localhost/projects/ibill_v3/html/loginform.html');
   echo "Wrong details";
  exit();
}
//If login details are incorrect

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
?>
```

**HMTL CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1; minimum-scale=1;">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <link href="/projects/ibill_v3/css/mainstyles.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
  <link href="/projects/ibill_v3/css/loginform.css" rel="StyleSheet"/>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
                $('.loginform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
                    // rules & options
                });
            });  
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<!--********************************LOGIN FORM PAGE**********************************************-->
<!--****************************************************************************************-->

<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->
<div data-role="page" id="loginform">
  <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Register</h1>
  </div>
<!--********************************HEADER**********************************************-->

<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <img class="mainlogo" src="/projects/ibill_v3/img/ibill logo.png" alt="iBill Logo" width="250" height="190">
    <h2>Sign in</h2>
    <section class="loginform">
      <form data-ajax="false" method="POST" action="loginform.php" > 
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="required" minlength="5" placeholder="enter username (min-5 characters)">
          </li>
          <li>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter password"  minlength="6">
          </li>

          <div id="loginformbutton">
            <button class='active' type='submit' value='submit'>Sign in</button>
          </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? Sign up!</p>
          <div id="registerbutton">
            <a href="/projects/ibill_v3/html/register.html" data-role="button">Register</a>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </section>

  </div>
<!--********************************MAIN**********************************************-->

<!--********************************FOOTER**********************************************-->
  <div data-role="footer">
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>awilliams&copy;</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<!--********************************END OF LOGIN FORM PAGE**********************************************-->
<!--****************************************************************************************-->
</body>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Comment: @PedroLobito That tutorial has plain-text passwords and doesn't use prepared statements. It's a stellar example of what not to do. This is a solved problem in any framework. Just use whatever they provide. No need to re-invent the wheel and do it badly.

Comment: Please consider the case where: $_POST['username'] = `"administrator"`, $_POST['password'] = `"0' OR 1=1 -- "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
else 
{
    header('Location:    http://localhost/projects/ibill_v3/html/loginform.html');
   echo "Wrong details";
   exit();
}
```

The above is going to redirect before your `echo` statement is reached, so nothing will be displayed.

Secondly, the following line:
`<form data-ajax="false" method="POST" action="loginform.php" >` will not send any data back to your file containing the form if you're using `echo` statements. It is going to redirect to the `loginform.php` and will stay there if you do not explicitly redirect back the page with your form.

Instead, use: 
`<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` as your form's action. And then include your `loginform.php` somewhere before the form in your HTML.
This is going to send data back to the form's file and replaces special characters to HTML entities (for security), it also allows you to use `echo`'s or variables to return messages to the user.
`loginform.php` will need to check if specific inputs are posted:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'])
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```

Here is a basic php form tutorial to start you off: [php tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your redirecting to the same page with no post.  I didn't look through all the code, that is just my first stab at it

Answer (score 0):

This will not appear on loginform.html:

```
echo "Wrong details";
```

Use something like:

```
$_SESSION['errorMessage'] = "Wrong details";
header('Location: http://localhost/projects/ibill_v3/html/loginform.html');
exit();
```

And then on loginform.html, add this code to display the error message:

```
if(isset( $_SESSION['errorMessage'])) echo $_SESSION['errorMessage'];
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried it but to no avail. I put the last snippet of code inside the form tag in the html file and enclosed it in php tags? Is this wrong?

Comment: The last snippet should be enclosed in php tags.

Comment: Are you using PHP sessions? Be sure to include 

    session_start();

inside PHP tags at the very beginning of both pages: the one where the session variable is being set, and the one where the session variable is being displayed.

Comment: still no joy...:( :(

Comment: Are you getting an error message or seeing anything strange? Could be that php isn't working with the loginform.html page.

Comment: no error messages, php is working as it is redirecting to http://localhost/projects/ibill_v3/html/loginform.html

Comment: A plain html page won't execute PHP unless you've changed your .htaccess file.

Comment: Maybe change loginform.html to loginform.php?